# how to redirect http call to https in delphi web server?

Tags: delphi, http, https, webserver

How to redirect HTTP call to HTTPS in delphi web server. I'm using Delphi stand alone web server and i installed SSL in my server. when I give request protocol as HTTPS, it working but I want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. Can any one tell how to redirect?

Comment: What web server are you using exactly?

Comment: we can create stand alone web servers in delphi. we used indy 10.5.7 components to create this server.

Answer (score 5):

If you have direct access to the webserver (e.g. you are creating an isapi or apache module) itself and you are in charge of the response you should use an http redirect as described on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Another (not recommended) variant is to output a html file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.anewsite.com/">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Like this:" - I think you forgot to type what.

Comment: Wouldn't the URL in the redirect be `https`?

Comment: @WarrenP: yes it would - it was just ment as an example - you can put whatever url you want into that field.